# My /home partition became full after moving files from encrypted user folder to unencrypted user folder. What can I do?

Tags: 13.04, ecryptfs

I'm currently working on removing my home directory encryption by following the instructions given by `ecryptfs-setup-private --undo`.

I have exited the graphical session and logged in on a tty in order to move all files from ~ to a temporary location (on the same partition as /home) and thus from /home I issued the following command: `find ~ -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -not -name .Private -and -not -name .ecryptfs -exec mv '{}' -t zoopp.unencrypted \;`.

The command moved about 30% of the files and then it stopped due to insufficient space. When I checked the output of 'df -h' I noticed that the home partition is full.

Before starting the move operation I had about 70GB of free space and since as far as I'm aware ecryptfs does not compress files I thought everything will be alright.

What can I do in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently some deeply buried files were left behind by mv (they were not deleted after being copied).

I found and deleted them with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

TARGET=/home/zoopp.unencrypted/
SOURCE=/home/zoopp/


find $TARGET -type f | while read file; do
    RELATIVE_PATH=$(echo $file | sed -e 's/^\/home\/zoopp.unencrypted\///')
    if [ -e "$SOURCE$RELATIVE_PATH" ]; then
        TARGET_FILE="$TARGET$RELATIVE_PATH"
        SOURCE_FILE="$SOURCE$RELATIVE_PATH" 

        echo "Found $TARGET_FILE -> $SOURCE_FILE"

        MD5_TARGET=$(md5sum "$TARGET_FILE" | cut -d' ' -f 1)
        MD5_SOURCE=$(md5sum "$SOURCE_FILE" | cut -d' ' -f 1)

        echo -e "\tMD5: $MD5_TARGET -> $TARGET_FILE"
        echo -e "\tMD5: $MD5_SOURCE -> $SOURCE_FILE"

        if [ "$MD5_TARGET" != "$MD5_SOURCE" ]; then
            echo -e "\tMissmatch."
            echo -e "\tDeleting $TARGET_FILE."
            rm -f "$TARGET_FILE"

            echo -e "\tMoving $SOURCE_FILE -> $TARGET_FILE"
            mv "$SOURCE_FILE" "$TARGET_FILE"
        else
            echo -e "\tMatch. Deleting $SOURCE_FILE"
            rm -f "$SOURCE_FILE"
        fi

        echo
    fi
done
```

As a side note: it would have been faster to just check for a difference in file size instead comparing the MD5 hash of every possible duplicate.